# What's the proper use of ListBox control and case statement in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2010, and am trying to get a textbox control named txtCamposOrden to return text based on multiple selection in a ListBox control named lstExamenes using the event AfterUpdate() and the Case statement, but I get Mismatch error; if I leave the listbox control empty the textbox does return the text after the "Case Else" part of the code. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub lstExamenes_AfterUpdate()
'Evaluate listbox control lstExamenes:

Select Case lstExamenes.Value

Case "BHC;EGO"

'Generate fields belonging to selected analysis:
txtCamposOrden.Value = "Hematocrito"

Case "BHC;VDRL"
txtCamposOrden.Value = "Hematocrito; VDRL"

Case Else
txtCamposOrden.Value = "PLEASE EDIT RESULT FOR THIS SELECTION"
End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Listbox is UNBOUND and multi-select? Code must loop through listbox selection set. Otherwise, try: `lstExamenes.Column(0)`.

Comment: Thanks! I had the multi-select Listbox control bound to a field in a table but after your suggestion I left it unbound. I also changed the event trigger to GotFocus() on the textbox control, and made the code to COPY the listbox.value to the textbox and I´m not getting any error message now BUT found out that the Listbox.value property was NOT being copied to the textbox control.  Any ideas?

Comment: Again, if you allow multiple selection, code must loop through listbox selection to build string. Otherwise, expression in textbox ControlSource: `=lstExamenes.Column(0)`. But why save listbox value(s) to a textbox?

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for your support! I really appreciate it. Quick followup question: how do I do this?: "code must loop through listbox selection to build string". As for your 2nd question, you're right, my main objective is not to have a string of the values in the textbox but to ultimately make a string of the lab work to be performed on the patient's sample which will be printer on a report as a checklist.

Comment: Google the topic of multi-select listbox - many examples. This article has one http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have already continue to study the suggested topic.